# Dataproc import python module stored in google cloud storage (gcs) bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, python-import, google-cloud-dataproc

I have following structure on GCS bucket :

1. my_bucket/notebooks/jupyter/

   - modules

     - mymodule.py
     - **init**.py
   - notebook_1.ipynb

How do i import mymodule in notebook_1.ipynb? (notebook_1.ipynb is a python notebook, NOT spark notebook)

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid it wouldn't be possible, since you need to have the module either in the directory where you are running the script or in your [**sys.path**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).

---

As an option, you can implement a function that would download the module from your Cloud Storage, use its functionality and then remove it.

Here is a simple **example** that I wrote for testing purposes:

*greetings.py* (the file that I stored in my bucket):

```
def say_hello(name):
    return "Hello {}!".format(name)


def say_hi(name):
    return "Hi {}!".format(name)
```

*main.py*:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import os


def get_module():
    """
    Instantiate Storage Client and return the blob located in the bucket.
    """
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket('<my-bucket-name>')
    return bucket.blob('greetings.py')


def use_my_module(my_method, val):
    """
    Download the module, use it and then remove.    
    """
    blob = get_module()
    blob.download_to_filename('my_module.py')
    import my_module

    result = getattr(my_module, my_method)(val)
    os.remove('my_module.py')
    return result


print(use_my_module('say_hello', 'User 1'))
print(use_my_module('say_hi', 'User 2'))
```

**Output**:

```
Hello User 1!
Hi User 2!
```

---

I cannot say if the example above is going to be efficient for your scenario but I hope that it will give you some ideas.

---

### Edit:

Regarding the situation that your module is located in a **sub-directory** of the directory with your script *(notebook_1.ipynb)* - you can import the module like this:

```
import modules.mymodule
```

Then you can use it with the following structure:

```
modules.mymodule.<your-method>
```

Comment: How can I apply this code to function with many arguments?