# Is there a way to import and run functions from saved .py files in a Jupyter notebook running on a Google Cloud Platform dataproc cluster?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, cluster-computing, google-cloud-dataproc

When running Jupyter notebook natively it is simple to import functions and utilities from a saved .py script.

When I work in a Jupyter notebook running on a Google Cloud Platform dataproc cluster and try the same thing- (after having uploaded a .py script to my dataproc Jupyter notebook- it is therefore in the cloud***) I am unable to import the function into the (dataproc) notebook.

Does anyone know how I can do this? Does it just have to do with figuring out the correct, but not obvious path? (I am trying to import a .py file from within the same folder as the Jupyter notebook, so if this were running natively it wouldn't require a path, but perhaps it is different with dataproc?

*** I am not making the mistake of trying to import a desktop/native .py script into a GC dataproc notebook.

Any help or leads would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not supported. But you can download the `.py` file then import, as a workaround - details can be found in the answer in a similar question:
[Dataproc import python module stored in google cloud storage (gcs) bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58832044/dataproc-import-python-module-stored-in-google-cloud-storage-gcs-bucket?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! A follow-up question would be: any resources as to how to make this happen if the function I'd like to import uses pyspark? I got the example to work and then I came up with an issue when I realized using spark in a function would be problematic. I keep getting "spark is not defined". I am guessing it has something to do with importing a .py file and using a function in that file that was meant for a pyspark kernel where you can just import pyspark.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PySpark kernel, you can add dependencies to sparkContext.

```
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile(f'gs://{your_bucket}/{path_to_file}/dependencies.zip')
```

Your dependencies.zip would contain a folder with all .py scripts and `__init__.py`:

```
dependencies/
├── __init__.py
└── my_script.py
```

You can then import all of your dependencies using

```
import dependencies
```

or import individual dependencies using

```
from dependencies.my_script import my_class
```

PS: Any changes to your dependencies.zip would not be reflected in your imports and you'll have to restart PySpark kernel to use the updated scripts.