# Run .py file from google cloud dataproc python notebook

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I have my files placed on dataproc storage as:

- inotebook.ipynb
- dependencies

  - test1.py
  - test2.py
  - __ init __.py

And currently working on inotebook.ipynb file and need to use functions in test1.py and test2.py files. Locally, I can use !python ....py and use functions available (or create a package and install). Is any of these options available on google cloud dataproc notebook?

I tried suggestions from below links and none worked:

- [Dataproc import python module stored in google cloud storage (gcs) bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58832044/dataproc-import-python-module-stored-in-google-cloud-storage-gcs-bucket?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- [Is there a way to import and run functions from saved .py files in a Jupyter notebook running on a Google Cloud Platform dataproc cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63179451/is-there-a-way-to-import-and-run-functions-from-saved-py-files-in-a-jupyter-not)

Is there anyway to install a custom package or somehow run .py files from same sub-directory as my notebook file on dataproc?

Comment: Have you tried `%load` or `%run`? See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHYDLni7UMY

Comment: These commands only work locally, I am looking for something to run a python script or load a module on google cloud dataproc python notebook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it is still a limitation of dataproc on using custom packages that are stored in GCS. I was able to make the [mentioned workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58832044/dataproc-import-python-module-stored-in-google-cloud-storage-gcs-bucket?answertab=votes#tab-top) work with a few changes. I added defining of `prefix` to be able to properly point to the correct files under a directory and looping through the returned object to download the files to the local dataproc cluster and execute the succeeding lines of code. See code below:

**GCS bucket structure:**

```
my-bucket
  └───notebooks
        └───jupyter
            |   gcs_test.ipynb
            └───dependencies
                  └─── hi_gcs.py
                  └─── hello_gcs.py
```

**hi_gcs.py:**

```
def say_hi(name):
    return "Hi {}!".format(name)
```

**hello_gcs.py:**

```
def say_hello(name):
    return "Hello {}!".format(name)
```

**gcs_test.ipynb:**

```
from google.cloud import storage

def get_module():

    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket('my-bucket')
    blobs = list(client.list_blobs(bucket,prefix='notebooks/jupyter/dependencies/'))
    # define the path to your python files at prefix
    for blob in blobs[1:]: # skip 1st element since this is the top directory
        name = blob.name.split('/')[-1] # get the filename only
        blob.download_to_filename(name) # download python files to the local dataproc cluster
    
def use_my_module(val):
    get_module()
    import hi_gcs 
    import hello_gcs 

    print(hello_gcs.say_hello(val))
    print(hi_gcs.say_hi(val))

use_my_module('User 1')
```

Output:

```
Hello User 1!
Hi User 1!
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this seems working to some extent. My question is now how to pass output of the called function to another variable? For example, when I try to pass hello_gcs.say_hello(val) to a new variable "msg", and have msg = hello_gcs.say_hello(val) and next line I print(msg), it prints None?

Comment: Actually if I have any other output beside text, it seems working. I defined hello_gcs.say_hello to return a dict of {"testing dict": "Hello {}!".format(name)} and I can pass the output of hello_gcs.say_hello(val) to msg and use in other lines of code, setting your response as the accepted response, thanks for the help.

Comment: @AziM with regards to your 1st follow up question, it works fine for me. Can you try `return msg` instead? But it is good to know that it worked for you!

Comment: using "return" works, thanks for the help. Now I am having another issue with a little more complicated .py file, where I have multiple classes and each has its own attributes. I update one of the attributes during a single call to a main function on the .py file, let's call it "features", and extend a value to it. The next time I run the use_my_module to call same main function, features is updated with the extended value! Looks like I would need to run some cleaning after each run of a main function. Have you seen such behavior? and do I need to remove ".py" file from blob storage? Thanks

Comment: You can post a new question with regards to this so it can be easily visualized and reproduced using your current code. Also the community will have a chance to contribute.