# Imports failing with workaround in Google Dataproc Cluster Notebooks

Tags: pyspark, import, cluster-computing, dataproc

I am running several experiments in notebooks running on a Spark Dataproc cluster.  Many of the functions stay the same from experiment to experiment (such as data preprocessing).  But, after some experiments, I realize some of the preprocessing needs to be tweaked then I have to go back and make the change in every duplicated notebook.  I would prefer to script the functions so they can be used by all notebooks and changed just once.  I found a workaround for importing local modules [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58832044/dataproc-import-python-module-stored-in-google-cloud-storage-gcs-bucket/58877303#58877303?newreg=17ffc10ad7344e15b5c7b2cec0efdf2d).  And that generally works.  Except, if my utils.py file (where all of my imported modules live) has a spark import such as `from pyspark.sql import functions as F` the imported function can't seem to find that import when it runs.
Example code:
utils.py

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
def create_spark_df(table_name):
    # Create SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    return spark.read.format("bigquery").option("table",table_name).load()

def get_filtered_customers_table():
    customers = create_spark_df('customers_table_name')
    return (
        customers
        .where(F.col('email').isNotNull())
    )
```

notebook cell for workaround

```
from google.cloud import storage

def get_module():

    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket('gcs_bucket_name')
    blobs = list(client.list_blobs(bucket,prefix='notebooks/jupyter/path_to_utils'))
    #define the path to your python files at prefix
    for blob in blobs[1:]: # skip 1st element since this is the top directory
        name = blob.name.split('/')[-1] # get the filename only
        blob.download_to_filename(name) # download python files to the local dataproc cluster
    
    
def run_module(name, args=None):
    get_module()
    import utils
    
    if name=='filtered_customers':
        return utils.get_filtered_customers()
```

Notebook cell that calls the module

```
filtered_customers = run_module('filtered_customers')
```

Although I have `from pyspark.sql import functions as F` in both the notebook and the utils.py file, I still get this error: `NameError: name 'F' is not defined`.

Any ideas why this would be happening??

I've tried googling every way I can think of and I've added the psyspark import to the specific function and notebook cell.  No dice.  Really hoping to figure out IF there is a way to solve this.  Maybe I'm just out of luck.  I should also note that `create_spark_df` function without filtering works just fine AND has an import -> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession -> in utils.py.  Not sure why the import for functions specifically is causing an issue.  Also tried that without the alias.  At this point, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Could you please try adding your `utils.py` to the spark context using [`.addPyFile`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.addPyFile.html) at the end of `get_module()` after you download the utils file in the local cluster? You can do something like `spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("utils.py")`. Do this and try different combinations of function imports. Like first simply remove it from the `utils.py` and see if it working and so on with other combinations - and see if provides any progress.